# Connection refused (single machine system)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have electric running on a single machine and my ROS_MASTER_URI and ROS_IP are set to my computer's IP. I can launch all nodes (although some die later on), but some (not all) service calls failed. I then ran roswtf, and I got the following error:

```
ERROR: connection refused to [http://192.168.0.40:38282/]
```

(This is my computer's IP)

It was then followed by several other errors, proabaly due to the connection refused (disconnected nodes, can't connect to some services).

I guess I am missing something really simple, because I performed the same installation on another machine a couple weeks ago (on the same network) and I didn't have this type of problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34591/connection-refused-(single-machine-system)/) by [iomartin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2359/iomartin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-05-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-05-22**:
Are you running any sort of firewall on this machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you sure that the nodes providing the services that fail are still running (i.e. they didn't segfault). If these nodes are written in C++, are they spinning (i.e. is ros::spin() called or is ros::spinOnce() executed periodically)?

These connection errors normally occur when a node didn't unregister cleanly from the master. That happens when they are killed with SIGKILL or when the nodes segfault. To find out which node is providing a service, you can use rosservice info, e.g. `rosservice info foo`. Then do a `rosnode info <node name>` to find out if the node is still alive.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1